# Display elements of SortedDictionary in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Long story short I want to make elements of a SortedDictionary appear as a list in a LongListSelector. Previously I was using a simple List and the XAML for it was pretty straightforward but then something came up and I was forced to use a SortedDictionary.

Comment: And where exactly is a problem? It would be nice, if you could show piece of your code that is supposed to show SortedDictionary in LongListSelector :)

Comment: If you could post some part of your code?